# Is Stack Overflow only for programming topics?

Tags: discussion, scope

Is this site only for programming topics? What I mean is that in order to produce content of the type of user behavior in any field or subject for the use of programs published by programmers, don't these contents require external experience and different jobs? For example, I am a civil engineer.

For example, a programmer produces an application about the field of civil engineering. My question is whether during the development of the software, don't these contents require external experience and different jobs? For example, I am a civil engineer. For example, a programmer produces an application about the field of civil engineering.

My question is whether during strong texting the development of the software Is there no need for my experience in the field of construction to help build this construction software?

Comment: However the question is rather unclear, and I am not sure it will be accepted for migration there. The short answer is that most programming questions are on-topic here, even if they are also related to another field, such as civil engineering.

Comment: "*Is there no need for my experience in the field of construction to help build this construction software*". No. No there is not. A project brief should be specific enough to allow someone with no industry knowledge to be able to produce the desired results. Though this is not a question for StackOverflow.

Comment: What do you mean by *"during strong texting"*?

Comment: The keyword may be [domain knowledge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_knowledge) or how to apply domain knowledge effectively.

Comment: For illustration, can you [add](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/419620/edit) one or more ***examples*** of what kind questions you would like to ask? (But ************** ***without*** ***************** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written right now)

Comment: A question like *"How can I best apply my domain knowledge as a civil engineer in software development"?* would not be well received.

Comment: The answer to such a broad question is always *"It depends"*. Can you narrow it down to something more specific?

Comment: "Is there no need for my experience in the field of construction to help build this construction software?" - yes. But not on Stack Overflow. When working on projects that require expertise from a specific field, that expertise is generally on-site. To give a silly example, there should never be a need for a software engineer to ask on Stack Overflow how a rocket ship works; the space agency they are contracted for will provide that information.

Answer (score 11):

> For example, a programmer produces an application about the field of civil engineering. My question is whether during the development of the software, don't these contents require external experience and different jobs?

The programmer will come to Stack Overflow in order to **ask a question**. The question needs to be about a programming topic in order to be [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). It says right there:

> but if your question generally covers…
>
> - a specific programming problem, or
> - a software algorithm, or
> - software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
> - a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development
>   …then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

If the question is about *how to write the code in order to get the right answer*, then expertise in non-programming fields does not matter. A civil engineer should have already explained to the programmer (or written some specification document, etc.) what the code needs to do.

If the question is about *what the right answer is*, or in other words *what the code needs to do*, then it is not on topic for Stack Overflow. The programmer [is expected to](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) figure out what the code needs to do first. That might involve talking to a civil engineer at work, or perhaps *on an actual discussion forum, which Stack Overflow is not*. It is only possible to write code for a task when that task is properly specified.

Answer (score 6):

Stack Overflow is for programming questions only, not for questions about the domain knowledge required to write specific types of programs.

If you want to ask about one of those areas, feel free to ask about it on one of the other Stack Exchange sites. You can also propose a site on the topic on [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/) if it doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 1):

Programming is the process to abstract the definitions, models, actions into code that the computers are able to understand. A programmer ideally should not know anything about what it's working on. There should be documents that describe with enough detail so that it can abstract it. Now, that ideally doesn't happen, doesn't mean programmers should know an iota of what they are doing.

I studied economics as an adult, I know not to speak to programmers about things they are not supposed to understand, I just describe with math what I'm doing, if I need to, I even would provide the formula, but I wouldn't start speaking about an creating an input-output model, a programmer wouldn't understand it. If I talk about matrices multiplication and doing so recursively, now I'm speaking their idiom. You could say that I'm cheating, and actually speaking math, but math is *the universal language* after all, and one that describe computer programs perfectly. If you can't speak about your field in a common language, without using jargon, then you would need someone to translate for you.

When speaking to a programmer, speak to it as if is a computer, with a very limited set of valid queries and understanding of concepts, since after all, a programmer would translate your "human" language to a "computer" language, and avoiding misinterpretations would do that easier and avoid mistakes.